# Is there a way to install GLFW 3.3.9/3.4 with NuGet

Tags: nuget, glfw

I am looking to install GLFW 3.3.9+  for use in my visual studio project  for a school project, and therefore need to use NuGet for GLFW.

**I am NOT ‘too lazy to use CMake’, my school wont give me command prompt access or install it.**

I am on a windows 10 machine with Visual Studio 17.7.5 2022 if that clarifies anything.

The only place that I’ve seen 3.3.9 is on their GitHub. There is a release note for 3.4 on their website, but it isn’t available for download. In their prebuilt bianaries, there is no version for 3.3.9+.

As for NuGet, I have tried changing the version but the latest possible is the latest stable - no unfinished/beta versions.